# assign static final variable in a static try-catch

Tags: java, exception, static, final

I want to read a property for config file and assign it to a `static final` variable and if in case the config file is omit/or not exists, using default value hard-coded.

```
public static final String NOTIFY_ALI;
static  {
    try {
        PropertyReader notifyConf = new PropertyReader("notify.conf");
        NOTIFY_ALI = notifyConf.getProperty("notify_ali","http://notify.foo.com/notify");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        NOTIFY_ALI = "http://notify.foo.com/notify";
    }
}
```

`NOTIFY_ALI` should be assigned by the configure file `notify.conf` with the key `notify_ali` or if it's not explicit in the file, take `http://notify.foo.com/notify` as a default value. And if the config file is not exists(`IOException` will occur), just catch the exception and assign with the default value as well.

But the upper code snippet give a compile time Err:

```
Error:(18, 13) java: variable NOTIFY_ALI might already have been assigned
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method that returns the URL and use to assign it when is declared

```
public static final String NOTIFY_ALI = getURL() ;

private static String getURL()
{ 
    String aux ;

    try {
        PropertyReader notifyConf = new PropertyReader("notify.conf");
        aux = notifyConf.getProperty("notify_ali","http://notify.foo.com/notify");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        aux = "http://notify.foo.com/notify";
    }
    return aux ; 
}
```

If you need to initialize more than one variable you could do it like this

```
public static final InitVariables IV = initVariables() ;

public class InitVariables {
    String NOTIFY_ALI ;
    String CONTACT_EMAIL ;
    int numEmployees ; 
}

private static InitVariables initVariables()
{ 
    InitVariables iv ;

    iv = new InitVariables() ;

    try {
        PropertyReader notifyConf = new PropertyReader("notify.conf");
        aux = notifyConf.getProperty("notify_ali","http://notify.foo.com/notify");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        aux = "http://notify.foo.com/notify";
    }

    iv.NOTIFY_ALI = aux ;

    iv.CONTACT_EMAIL = "you@somedomain.com";
    iv.numEmployees = 0 ;

    return iv ; 
}
```

Comment: @armnotstrong I just improved my answer that should work 99% sure ;-)

Comment: Do you mean that the **improved** answer will prevent the case that `static` block might not be invoked or not invoked properly?

Comment: @armnotstrong I just added another sample on another aproach to initialize multiple variables and still follow the same pattern

Comment: Thank you for given a more generic solution :D

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove the static initializer block and create a static method whose result is assigned to your static final variable?

```
public static final String NOTIFY_ALI = init();

private static String init() {
    try {
        PropertyReader notifyConf = new PropertyReader("notify.conf");
        return  notifyConf.getProperty("notify_ali","http://notify.foo.com/notify");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "http://notify.foo.com/notify";
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean the same as my answer ;-) ?

Comment: This will be nice, but, in fact, there are more than just one variable that should share the same init logic. It' my fault that I didn't explicit that in the origin post.

Comment: Update your post and we'll help you find a solution

Comment: @armnotstrong you can wrap all your initial variables into a class and make the method return reference to that class with the initialized values